# Find the derivative of $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\tan \left(\sqrt{x}\right)\right)$ - no chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to find the derivative of:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\tan \left(\sqrt{x}\right)\right)
$$

As per the chain rule I have to find the derivative of $tan()$ and then $(\sqrt{x})$ which at the end is equal to $\frac{\sec ^2\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{2\sqrt{x}}$

However, in my exercise, I don't have to use the chain rule nor L'Hopital rule.

I'm looking to re-write $\tan(\sqrt{x})$ in a way to solve the exercise. I'm thinking of

$$
\lim _{h\to 0}\left(\frac{\tan\left(\sqrt{x+h}\right)-\tan\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{h}\right)
$$

but I'm kind of lost on how to solve it

Comment: What happens if the limit definition is applied? You can also rewrite the tangent function as a sum, differentiate, and find the closed form of the sum with no chain rule.

Comment: I thought the chain rule was the general rule for "combined functions".

Comment: In any event, nothing at that link supports your way of finding that derivative.

Comment: @GerryMyerson if you study math, you should know that teachers may require you to do exercises by the long way... your comment is not helpful

Comment: I did study math, David. Got a Bachelor's Degree in it, and a Master's, and a PhD, and then taught it at university level for forty years. Anyway, I don't know what you mean by "the long way", unless you mean go back to the definition of the derivative as the limit of a certain quotient. But I repeat that there is nothing at the link you give that supports the answer $\sec^2\sqrt x$. The "combined functions" method at that link includes the chain rule, and the chain rule is how you get that $1/(2\sqrt x)$ – that's the derivative of $\sqrt x$.

Comment: OK, now I see your edit, and you are going back to the difference-quotient definition of the derivative. So the combined functions link was a red herring, right? Are you sure that you are supposed to do it that way, and not permitted to use the chain rule? I would never have asked my students to evaluate a complicated derivative that way, not after we had the chain rule available.

Comment: @GerryMyerson we have different topics every week (as well as exercises to do as per the methods we learn), we have seen the basic rules for derivatives except the chain rule. I've studied the chain rule online and definitely, it's easier. But I think I'll do the chain rule on this one.

Comment: @DavidSalomon Hint: $\,\tan(a) - \tan(b) = \frac{\sin(a-b)}{\cos(a)\cos(b)}\,$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first show your work so others can see where you went wrong. Anyway I think I know where is the mistake as I myself have done same mistake in past. So here is my solution

Using first principle of derivative we can write,
$$\frac{d}{dx}\tan(\sqrt{x}) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\tan(\sqrt{x+h})-\tan(\sqrt{x})}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h \to0} \frac{\sin(\sqrt{x+h})\cos(\sqrt{x})-\cos(\sqrt{x+h})\sin(\sqrt{x})}{h\cos(\sqrt{x+h})\cos(\sqrt{x})}$$
$$=\lim_{h \to0} \frac{\sin(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x})}{h\cos(\sqrt{x+h})\cos(\sqrt{x})}$$
Applying algebra of limits we can write it as
$$=\lim_{h \to0} \frac{\sin(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x})}{h}.\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{\cos(\sqrt{x+h})\cos(\sqrt{x})}$$
The second limit evaluates to $\sec^2(\sqrt{x})$ and possibly at this point you made the mistake by putting first limit equal to 1. But it is not so.
We multiply and divide by $(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x})$ and get
$$\frac{d}{dx}\tan(\sqrt{x}) = \sec^2(\sqrt{x})\lim_{h \to0} \frac{\sin(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x})}{h}.\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}$$
$$=\sec^2(\sqrt{x})\lim_{h \to0} \frac{\sin(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}.\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}$$

Now it is easy to see that the first limit gives 1 and the second one evaluates to $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ finally giving
$$\frac{d}{dx}\tan(\sqrt{x}) = \frac{\sec^2(\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: Or, for the last step: $\;\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x})}{h} = \frac{\sin(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}} \to 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: Thank you so much Shivam, that's what I was looking for, actually I was doing the @dxiv solution and I was going to edit my question with my findings... Thank you dxiv for your suggestions as well

Comment: You are welcome @DavidSalomon